# What is the best solution for Local Notifications in IOS for react native?

Tags: react-native

As the React Native website informs us [PushNotificationsIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios) is now deprecated. What is recommended is using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios. However, this project does not seem to be maintained or commonly utilized. Frustratingly, it lacks Typescript support.

I am having problems using a Notification Content Extention for some nice custom iOS notifications. I suspect this has something to do with react-native-push-notification-ios's use of now deprecated **UILocalNotification**. Like many projects in the elephant graveyard that is the RN ecosystem, it seems painfully out of date. I'm reluctant to further troubleshoot my issues because it seems like a lonely, time consuming and potentially fruitless effort. Additionally, I'm trying to avoid writing a lot of native code.

Is there a solution I am missing here? Or am I asking for too much native support from React Native?

Answer (score 1):

I always use firebase for my notifications. It works really well in my opinion. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/introduction

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using rnfirebase v6 and the maintainers just recently announced notifications will not be migrated from v5 and there is no backwards compatibility. Nothing can be easy, can it :(

Comment: Yes, I know. We use v5 because of that problem. If someone has a solution for this I really want to know.